# Flask proxy server

Tags: python, flask, http-proxy

I'm trying to create a really really simple proxy server in `Flask`. I'm a beginner trying to get the basics down here. I'd ideally like the output from here to seem like you were just going to the site directly. I'm unsure if this is impossible to do or not.

I found the following [code:](https://medium.com/@zwork101/making-a-flask-proxy-server-online-in-10-lines-of-code-44b8721bca6)

```
from flask import Flask
from requests import get

app = Flask(__name__)
SITE_NAME = 'http://google.com'

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def proxy(path):
    return get(f'{SITE_NAME}{path}').content

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

This is almost exactly what I want. Example of what the output is (for http://google.com)
[image]

Is there any way to render out the `javascript` and images? Is this impossible?

Comment: try this, https://gist.github.com/stewartadam/f59f47614da1a9ab62d9881ae4fbe656

Answer (score 1):

You should really add a slash when rendering the request URL: `f'{SITE_NAME}/{path}'`. Add a `print` statement and you'll notice you're requesting things like `http://google.comtextinputassistant/tia.png` .

Also, proxying isn't as simples as that. You should clone all request headers sent by the client and send it to google.com and do de reverse when dealing with the response. Check how differently are the responses from `https://www.google.com/textinputassistant/tia.png` and `https://localhost:5000/textinputassistant/tia.png`, inspect the request and response headers from both URLs and you will notice how much info is being lost.

Comment: I see. For the google page, for instance, one GET request is originating from localhost (`GET http://localhost:5000/logos/doodles/2021/celebrating-the-letter-n-6753651837108360.2-l.png 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)`). not sure what to do to do like you said and repeat all the requests. any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Check out @marcus-aurelianus comment. There is an interesting gist.